# Why Ubuntu 18.04- ALT+F4 closes all windows, on pressing combination only once?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, shortcut-keys

I used Ubuntu 16.04, but in U18.04, when I use the combination of <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, it closes all windows along with the background windows until it reaches the desktop screen and no other app is running.

It happens mostly when I use VLC.
Also for other apps as well.

Expected behavior: It should close only the current window/app.

Actual behavior: It closes other windows along with the current one.

Is this a bug or my mistake?

I don't press keys for a long time, which could cause closing all windows.

Comment: This is not the designed behaviour and I cannot reproduce this. Does it also happen with multiple windows of nautilus or firefox? Perhaps your keyboard repeat delay is set too low, and repeat rate too high.

Comment: yes it happens with other apps as well. how can I, make keyboard repeat delay long?

Comment: Are you using an HP ENVY notebook by any chance?

Comment: No man, mine is Dell 3557 core i3 laptop